Dynamic of a particle when it falls into a rotating black hole
I guess when a particle falls in a rotating black hole its accelerate is not constant. I wonder is there any equation that calculate accelerate of a particle when it falls in a rotating black hole?

The geodesic equation determines how the particle falls in. But acceleration in curved spacetime can be defined in various ways, so this makes things more complicated than in flat spacetime. You need to think about what kind of observer is measuring the acceleration. Are they stationary at infinity? In orbit around the hole? Falling in themselves?

Is accelerate obsever dependent? Then i would know it from point of veiw of the both inertial and non inertial obsevers. When the particle falls in the blackhole before and after reaching the event horizon.
